Qemu version 2.9.0 and later doesn't support legacy networking mode on gns3
When i start my nodes in GNS3 i get the following error message : Q emu version 2.9.0 and later doesn't support legacy networking mode . How can i fix this. Do i have to do downgrade to a 2.8.0 version or should i somehow enable legacy networking mode. If i have to downgrade, how can i do it?
The only solution i found was to upgrade the Q emu version, but that obviously didn't fix the issue. There is a post on the issues on the GNS3  git that just say it's broken and an expired link
